# Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey not creating any sub key?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm trying to set a registry value using the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey;
    rkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("KEYSUB");
    rkey.SetValue("TestKey", "123123");

    RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("KEYSUB", true);

    if (myKey != null)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(myKey.ToString());
     }
}
```

but the myKey is always null and there is no folder created in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software or any where else.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in my case it creates it in the wrong place: WOW6432Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myKey is always null, because you create the key in CurrentUser, but query LocalMachine.

If you want to create the key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software, first open softwareKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software") and then softwareKey.CreateSubKey the key there.

Comment: `rkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("KEYSUB");` where it actually creating the KEYSUB folder?. Just curious.

Comment: @Sabir, in NT, registry hives are mounted under the "\Registry" Key object. System hives are mounted under the "\Registry\Machine" subkey, and user hives (i.e. "ntuser.dat") go under "\Registry\User" and are named for the user's security identifier (SID, e.g. "S-1-5-18"). The Windows API opens and caches handles for these keys, as well as the current user's subkey. The handle values are variable, depending on the first available handle at the time, so the API maps these handles to the predefined pseudo-handles HKLM, HKU, and HKCU. Thus "HKCU\KEYSUB" is really "\Registry\User\\[SID]\KEYSUB".